# Possessive quandary

Tags: grammar

While it is perfectly legitimate to say both:

> I enjoyed your company and your wife's.
>
> I enjoyed your wife's company and yours.

Which of the following is correct, and why?

> I enjoyed your and your wife's company?
>
> I enjoyed yours and your wife's company?

Comment: Also see at EL&U: *[How do you make the possessive form with "He and I"-style subjects?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/38849/77227)* and *[“My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/)*

Answer (score 1):

First off, while this is a fine question to satisfy a general interest, since "your" is plural you can just say:

> I've enjoyed **(both) your** company.

But to answer your question:  I believe the most common expression is the one that uses the combined possessive:

> I've enjoyed **you and your wife's** company.

Comment: Methinks it might sound a mite ambiguous, especially if there were a pause after *you*.

Comment: @RonaldSole  Well yeah, it totally changes the meaning if you add a significant pause after "you", just like the ["Let's eat, Grandma"](http://ted-ielts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Oxford-comma1.jpeg) joke, or the one about the [strippers, Stalin, and JFK.](https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-02/22/18/enhanced/webdr01/enhanced-buzz-6222-1424646182-17.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto).

Comment: Common thought it may be, I don't think it's correct grammar.

Comment: @dwilli You think that "your" as the plural possessive is not correct grammar?  Have you [checked a dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc)?

Comment: @Andrew, please give me more credit than that. I'm here to help find the right answer to the question, just like you. I was talking about your second example. My fault for not explaining myself better. You're correct that it's very common. Nobody would miss a beat on hearing it. It's awkward, though. The third person possessive with apostrophe and s works for 'your wife' but not really for the second person plural, 'you and your wife'. It's better said, 'I've enjoyed the company of you and your wife.' or I've enjoyed your and your wife's company. Your first example is great.

Answer (score 1):

“I enjoyed your and your wife's company?” is correct. Why? Because it’s an abbreviation for “I enjoyed your *company* and your wife’s company.”